# Can I see what each settler is assigned to?

Tags: fallout-4

Currently I have 11 settlers, hoping to get some more but I need more food.

However the issue is I can't tell which settlers are farming food, or doing 'other' things such as slacking off enjoying the radiation.

Is there anyway to see what each settler is up to in your settlement without selecting each on of them in turn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. And what's worse is you actually have to be in view of whatever they're assigned to as well, or you won't see it highlighted.

Comment: *With the exception of settlers assigned to a trade route, which are re-name to 'Provisioner' shortly after being assigned.

Comment: @GeneralMike That's a bit of a gray area. Yeah, you can tell what role they've been given. But you can't tell which settlements they're provisioning unless you're in a settlement that only has one link.